# Subnumbering in chemstyle

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, chemstyle

When I use `\schemeref` and `\schemerefsub`, instead of 1 and 2a 2b I get 1 and 1a 1b. So my subnumbering doesn't seem to follow my regular numbering, but when I refer to the compounds I get 1 and then, instead of 1a, 1b, 2 and 3. How can I get my subnumbering to follow my regular numbering and how to refer correctly to subnumbers?

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}                  

\usepackage{bpchem}
\usepackage[crop={off},runs={2}]{auto-pst-pdf} % Use EPS graphics with pdfLaTeX
\usepackage[tracking=bpchem]{chemstyle}

\usepackage{amstext} \usepackage{caption} \usepackage{kvoptions} \usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{varioref} \usepackage{floatrow} 

\begin{document}
%\immediate
%\write18{dir > listing}
%\IfFileExists{listing}{\message{\string\write18 ENABLED}}


\begin{figure}[h]
\schemeref[TM]{mainA}
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{epsfigx}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
 \schemeref[TMP]{mainB}
 \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{epsfigxx}
 \end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\schemerefsub[TMP1]{mainB}{a}
\schemerefsub[TMP2]{mainB}{b}
\schemerefsub[TMP3]{mainC}{aa}      
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{epsfigy}
\end{figure}

\compound{mainA}
\compound{mainB}
\compound{a}
\compound{b}
\compound{aa}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your arguments seem to be reversed: I assume that `a` is the main reference and that `et` is a sub-reference, in which case you want `\schemerefsub{a}{et}`.

Comment: Not really. The output I want is the first figure to labelled 1, then I have a figure with three structures and I want to label them 2a, 2b and 3a but instead of that, my numbering starts over with 1a 1b and 2a. And when I refer to \schemerefsub[TMP1]{et}{b} with \compound{b}, instead of 1b i get 3?

Comment: As I said, you seem to have the arguments backward. It's `\schemeref{<main>}{<sub>}`, so for example if `\schemeref{b}{et}` gives '**1b**', then `\schemeref{b}` will give '**1**'.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I've editted my script above to make my question more clearly: so the output I wish to achieve is the figures to be numbered 1, 2, 2a 2b and 3a but instead I get 1 2 1a 1b and 2a. And when I try to refer to for example 1a in the text i never get the subnumber?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing two methods of numbering. You tell `chemstyle` to use [`bpchem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bpchem) but in the document you're using `\compound` which is the [`chemcompounds`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemcompounds) command. You should use the `bpchem` commands `\CNlabel{<cpd>}`, `\CNref{<cpd>}`,`\CNlabelsub{<cpd>}{<sub>}` and `\CNrefsub{<cpd>}{<sub>}`.

Using these command the right way should clear most of the wrong numbers!

<strike>However, I also found a wrong numbering using this code:</strike> With version 2.0l of the `chemstyle` package (2012-01-28) this works as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{bpchem}
\usepackage[tracking=bpchem]{chemstyle}

\begin{document}
Compound 1a: \CNlabelsub{cpdA}{one}
Compound 2: \CNlabel{cpdB}

\begin{scheme}[h]
 \schemerefsub[TMP1]{cpdA}{one} % gives 1a
 \schemeref[TMP2]{cpdB}         % gives 2
 \includegraphics{scheme-tmp}
\end{scheme}

\end{document}
```

Version <2.0l needed

```
\makeatletter
\let\cst@ref@label\CNlabel
\makeatother
```

added to the preamble to fix wrong numbering.

---

An alternative would be to switch to the [`chemnum`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemnum) package for the numbering and use the commands `\cmpd` or `\replacecmpd`, resp.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{chemnum,chemstyle}
\setchemnum{ main-sub-sep = ! }

\begin{document}

Compound 1a: \cmpd{cpdA!one}
Compound 2: \cmpd{cpdB}

\begin{scheme}[h]
  \replacecmpd{cpdA!one} % gives 1a
  \replacecmpd{cpdB}     % gives 2
  \includegraphics{scheme-tmp}
\end{scheme}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed that fixes everything. Thanks a lot!